# Including a method in Rails

Tags: ruby, sqlite, module, sinatra

I want to include include a helper method in my controller file in order to perform the task of creating a new table in SQLite3. So in another file I've created a module called "Helper" with a method called "add_table(name)", with the objective of naming the table the passed in name. Here is what my module file looks like.

```
module Helper

def add_table(username)
    db = SQLite3::Database.new("helper_database")
    create_table = <<-SQL 
        CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS "#{username}" (
            id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY,
            user_id INT,
       );   
    SQL
    db.execute(create_table)
```

In my controller file I have required the ruby file at top. I have a form in the view file that will ask the user for a name, grab the name params following post request and insert that name into the method.

```
require_relative 'helper_method'
post '/new_user' do
    include Helper
    add_table(params[:username])
    redirect '/index' 
    end
```

any ideas on why I might be getting an undefined method error for "include"?

```
(undefined method `include' for #<Sinatra::Application:0x007feb24f5e5a8>)
```

Comment: The title says you want to include a method in Rails, but the question is tagged with Sinatra. Can you please clarify this?

Comment: its been edited by another user

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried something like this?

```
require_relative 'helper_method'
include Helper

post '/new_user' do
  add_table(params[:username])
  redirect '/index' 
end
```